# how to count week number of month using dataprep

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I tried to count week number of month using below code,but I got weird num like -48.(I know my logic is weird lol)

Could you point out the fault of below code to make weeknum of month.

I need sensei's help.

I used Dataprep

```
WEEKNUM(date)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(date),MONTH(date),1))
```

no error , but some values are -48,47......

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is mostly sound, except you're only thinking of `WEEKNUM` in the context of a single year. In order to have non-overlapping weeks, the week containing January 1 is always week `1` (regardless of the period), so in this case December 29–31, 2019 are all going to be week `1`, just like the following 4 days of January will be. It makes sense, but only when you think about it in context of multiple years.

You can work around this for your case by checking the `WEEKNUM` and `MONTH` values conditionally, and then outputting a different value:

```
IF(AND(MONTH(date) == 12,WEEKNUM(date) == 1),53,WEEKNUM(date)) - WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(date),MONTH(date),1))
```

While hard-coding the week number of 53 is a little hacky, the whole point of week numbers is to always have 52 subdivisions—so I don't really see any concerns there.

You may also want to add 1 to the resulting formula (unless you want your week numbers to start with 0 each month).